# Get current homescreen image

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode4

Is it actually possible to get a image of your current homescreen on the iPhone? 
I don't think this is possible, but I just want to be sure before trying anything else.

Comment: Nope, it'd be a privacy violation.

Comment: Just wondering... and do what with it?

Comment: Just for fun. Doing some cool effects. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not possible**, because of sandboxing regulations. The image on your homescreen can not be accessed by a third-party program.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible for your app to get an image of your homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now for iOS7 to get home screen image even without user allowing access to your photos in the privacy settings.  See (Vesper app)